# What's the meaning of `unit 0` and `family inet`?

Tags: juniper, juniper-junos

In my JunOS configure mode, I show the interfaces:

```
[edit]
root@Olive# show interfaces
em0 {
    unit 0 {
        family inet {
            address 192.168.47.2/24
        }
    }
}
em1 {
    vlan-tagging;
}
em2 {
    vlan-tagging;
}
em3 {
    vlan-tagging;
}
```

What's the meaning of `unit 0` and `family inet`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A physical interface can consists of multiple logical interfaces, each called a `unit`. Each unit has a number as a unique identifier. The `0` just refers to the first logical interface.

It's good practice (but not required) to keep the unit number in sync with the VLAN id. In that case `unit 0` often refers to the untagged interface.

`family inet` refers to the IPv4 address family. An interface can have configuration for multiple address families, each with their own specific configuration and purpose.

Comment: Teun, you might want to swap *physical* and *logical* in the first sentence... ;-)

Comment: eh, why exactly? I don't see anything wrong in how I described this. Units are logical interfaces.

Comment: I think you mean "a *logical* interface can consist of multiple *physical* interfaces". The other way around you've got to show me. ;-D