# What's the meaning of `unit 0` and `family ethernet-switching`?

Tags: juniper, juniper-junos

[What's the meaning of `unit 0` and `family inet`?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/52072/whats-the-meaning-of-unit-0-and-family-inet)

With the above question, I learned the meaning of `unit 0` and `inet`.

So what does **ethernet-switching** mean?

```
root@test> show configuration
...
...
interfaces {
    ge-0/0/0 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching {
                vlan {
                    members 1500;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
...
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It helps to look at a different kind of Junos interface configuration and compare.

The reason for `unit <n>` is to allow multiple, logical subinterfaces (IFLs) to exist within a given physical interface (IFD.)  (The definition of physical interface has blurred over time.)

The reason for `family <f>` is to separate configuration statements related to IPv4, IPv6, layer-2 switching/bridging, etc.

```
interfaces {
    ge-0/0/1 {
        flexible-vlan-tagging;
        unit 10 {
            vlan-id 10;
            family inet {
                address 192.0.2.1/24;
            }
            family inet6 {
                address 2001:db8::1/112;
            }
        }
        unit 11 {
            vlan-id 11;
            ....
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to add a quick comment - It helps to remember that IFD = "Interface Device", that can be a logical or physical.  In actuality, it simply comes down to hierarchy.